# Accessing field after creating instance of the class

Tags: scala, methods, private-members

I just read a tutorial from https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/classes.html of how to access private fields. What confuses me is what exactly is allowing me to modify the private variable. Below is a simplified code. According to the hompage it is the method `x_` for setting the field x_. If that is the case, then I should be able to change the method name to for example `def z` and then update my instance `point1.z= 99` but I get an error. What do I need to do in order to be able to use another method name?

```
class Point {
  private var _x = 0

  def x = _x
  def x_= (newValue: Int): Unit = {
    if (newValue < bound) _x = newValue else 0
  }

}
val point1 = new Point
point1.x = 99
```

Comment: This works: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/fpLiEGDHT8uAT8YlxINEQA/1 - In any case, I rarely use mutable variables in **Scala**, almost never they had a _public_ getter and setter, and never ever I needed a custom getter a setter.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thanks for the input. How come you we need to change the name of the first method as well. I cannot see the connection between these two methods.

Comment: The spec requires the setter and getter to both exist and be named the same. This is mostly for keeping some standard; if I am able to do `foo.x = y` then I should be able to do `foo.x` - Now, if you just make the `var` public, the both the getter and setter will be generated, in your case that is not possible because you want to do the bound check but again, in my 5 years of using **Scala** I never had to do something like that.

Comment: Yeah, [here's](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#assignments) the relevant spec part.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thanks for the explanation. I just want to know this concept but hopefully I will not need to use this in the future.

Comment: Don't do this. Seriously. Try writing your code pretending that `var` doesn't exist at all. You'll be really surprised how much you can do without this ugliness.